# Append data count onto different series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 2 datatime series (**A** & **B**)
Xaxis should be time and yaxis is count.

If time t i have 1 value on serie **A**, graph will show: [x=t, y=1].
If same time t i have one other value on serie **B**, I would like that value to be show: [x=t, y=2].

At the moment I modify 'manualy'  values on serie **B**.

I wonder if there os a built-in method in highcharts to have that behavior?
Thx

Comment: Do you want to have two series, where the second one will always have doubled values on corresponding timestamps? If so, then this is easy to achieve and can be done on load event. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jyh1nct7/.

Comment: No i want the next serie to be added on previous one.

Comment: Then you can calculate values the same way but instead of adding a new series, change the data of the first one. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hmrwuqnc/.

Comment: I understand, but results isn't the expected behavior.
I have a mailbox and I wan't to display each mail by a dot in my graph. I have three types of e-mails (personal, business & health) - currently these are my 3 series.
If I have 2 mails the same day I would like to see 2 points on the graph (one above the other - doesn't matter if is the same serie or not).
Tell me if is not clear enough. thx for paying attention

Comment: Ok, so in that case you would have to create some custom code that gets all data, checks for occurrences of the same dates and based on that information set appropriate y values for points. I have prepared a simple demo where all emails are correctly arranged on the chart. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywsh98f5/.

Comment: that is exactly the expected result. I did something similar but I thought maybe there is something "built-in" in highcharts.

Thank you, bthw Highcharts is a fantastic library. I really like it.

Comment: Put your comment as _answer_ so I can thumb up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so in that case you would have to create some custom code that gets all data, checks for occurrences of the same dates and based on that information set appropriate `y` values for points. I have prepared a simple demo where all emails are correctly arranged on the chart.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ywsh98f5

Comment: Hi @pawel_d, I think it's possible using stacking